# Відповідник до слова "страйкбол"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

[Страйкбол](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB) (англ. airsoft) — командна гра, у якій «бій» ведеться 6 мм кульками типу BB (вагою від 0,12 до 0,43 г) з точних копій бойової зброї.

В останній час гра стала популярную і в Україні, так само як і пейнтбол. Але якщо до останнього є відповідники на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/peintbol) - барвостріл, фарбострілялка тощо, то для "страйкболу" відповідника іще немає.

Саме слово "страйкбол" складається із англ. дієслова "strike" - "удар" та "ball" - "м'яч".

Чи можливо утворити відповідник до "страйкболу" на кшталт "барвострілу" чи "фарбострілялки" (однак, варто врахувати, що в СУМі немає слова "стрілялка", проте є слово "[стріл](http://sum.in.ua/s/stril)")?

Comment: Тут важко придумати назву без використання іншомовних слів, бо маємо 4 чимось схожі гри: _лазертаг_, _пейнтбол_, _страйкбол_, _хардбол_ — і треба їх якось розрізнити. Також зверніть увагу, що _страйкбол_ і _хардбол_ насправді, здається, **не** є запозиченнями. Англійською аналог _страйкболу_ називається _airsoft_ (а не _strikeball_, як можна було б подумати, слова _strikeball_ словники не знають) — імовірно, назву _страйкбол_ створили з англійських слів у Росії 1990-х; слово _хардбол_ зовсім не має перекладу англійською (не грають вони в хардбол; англійське _hardball_ — це різновид бейсболу).

Comment: Я маю на увазі — не є запозиченнями з англійської (а є російськими чи принаймні пострадянськими неологізмами). Тобто _страйкбол_ (термін, штучно складений, мабуть, росіянами з англійських слів) доречніше порівнювати зі словом _екологія_ (термін, штучно складений німцями з давньогрецьких слів), а не зі словом _футбол_ (насправді англійським словом).

Comment: Тобто, страйкбол -  це русизм, який був складений із англійських слів? Просто накнувшися на відповідник до пейнтболу (найбільше мені сподобався варіант барвостріл) я подумав, що було б добре добрати до інших схожих видів спорту подібні українські відповідники. В слові "страйкбол", на мою думку, залишилося замінити частинку "страйк-", а замість "-бол" використати частинку "-стріл".

Comment: Так, мені здається, що це саме росіянізм, складений з англійських слів. Буде важко підібрати перші частини, бо ми маємо щонайменше 4 види _<щось>стрілів_, кожна з яких потребує власної назви (якби це встановлювати централізовано, то можна було б _лазеростріл_ (чи _променестріл_?), _м'якостріл_ (чи _м'якопневмостріл_?), _твердостріл_ (чи _твердопневмостріл_?) і _фарбостріл_ — але чи сподобається це користувачам, адже _м'якостріл_ м'який лише в порівнянні з _твердострілом_, але не сам собою, а це, як я розумію, різні організації). Ну але спробуйте.

Comment: Може, _страйкбол_ — _пневмостріл_, а _хардбол_ — _твердопневмостріл_ чи _сильнопневмостріл_? (Або якщо _-пневмо-_ — занадто закордонне, то замінити на _-тиско-_ чи навіть _-духо-_.) Або _пневмостріл_ (_страйкбол_) і _твердостріл/сильностріл_ (_хардбол_ — оскільки цей вид з'явився останнім, то хай отримає коротку, але не дуже логічну назву)?

Comment: Варіант духостріл здається хорошим відповідником.

Comment: _Духостріл_ може позначати й щось [таке](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Духова_трубка), а не лише сучасну пневматичну зброю. Та й навіть якщо призвичаїти це слово до сучасної пневматики, можливо, воно буде більше асоціюватися з самою зброєю (_духостріл_ = _пневматичний пістолет_ (як на слензі _гумостріл_ = _травмат_)), а не з ігрою на її основі. Але, так, мабуть, це найкраще, що можна придумати.

Comment: Хоча ще можна долучити якийсь суфікс — наприклад, _-ини_ для деяких подій (_відвідини_, _оглядини_, _уводини_): _фарбострілини_ «пейнбол», _духострілини_ «страйкбол», _лазерострілини_ (_променестрілини_) «лазертаг», _сильнострілини/твердострілини_ «хардбол».

Comment: Так, звучить непогано і, здається, правилам українського словотвору не суперечить.